# Router shows my external IP as client's connection IP

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Whenever a client connects to my server (Does not really matter what server it is, this happens on every single one) the server shows my external IP address as an client's IP address. This bevahior is gone if I connect cable directly to my computer, it only happens if I have cable connected into WiFi before PC. In router everything is on default, using DHCP for WAN, tried disabling some features, still no luck.
Could not find any information in google, tried every single word combination that could make a problem's sentence, either nobody had this issue or i'm missing something.

EDIT: The issue was in firmware of my router, after upgrade everything was fixed

Comment: Where is the client, and where is the server? Are they inside your network or outside? Exactly what do you mean by "cable connected into WiFi"?

Comment: No, client is outside of my network. For example if i host a server in nodejs with local IP and then do port forwarding, whenever i connect from anywhere in the world the server shows my external IP address as client's ip, that is if i cable is not directly connected to PC. By 'cable connected to wifi' i mean the ISP cable is connected first into wifi and then another cable connected into my pc from wifi which grants me local ip.

Comment: `the server shows my external IP address` shows where?

Comment: ...by "wifi" do you mean something like a wireless router? (What model of device is it?)

Comment: @TomYan well, it shows as a socket's address, therefore in every application when you just print it it shows my external IP

Comment: @user1686 TP-Link Wireless N Router WR840N

Comment: How is the TP-Link connected to other things, i.e. which physical ports go where? ("cable" means a cable modem, I'm guessing?) How is your 'port forwarding' set up in all those devices?

Comment: @user1686 I have only one device connected to it and thats my pc. Using DHCP address reservation for it and port forwarding from that static local ip

Comment: @everyone Looks like problem was in my firmware, everything got fixed after I upgraded it. Thanks for trying to help